# Tensorflow TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'N

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
a=tf.Variable(0, name='input')
b=tf.constant(1)

mid_val =tf.add(a,b)
update_value =tf.compat.v1.assign(a,mid_val)
tg=initialize_all_variables()


with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tg)
  print(sess.run(a))

  for i in range(3):
    sess.run(update_value)
    print(sess.run(a))
```

It is giving me error in `sess.run(tg)` and raising a type error and on running it is giving following error:

```
<ipython-input-20-fd2283cdd3bd> in <module>()
     10 
     11 with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
---> 12   sess.run(tg)
     13   print(sess.run(a))
     14 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
    263     """
    264     if fetch is None:
--> 265       raise TypeError(f'Argument `fetch` = {fetch} has invalid type '
    266                       f'"{type(fetch).__name__}". Cannot be None')
    267     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
```

What should I do?

Comment: What TF version do you use? And what is `initialize_all_variables()`?

Comment: Most probably, it is `initialize_all_variables()` that has a problem.

Comment: I am using tensorflow 2.0 version

Answer (score 0):

You are running graph mode operations in eager execution mode (later versions of **TF 2.x**) which causes this error.

You need to **disable eager execution** mode to run the above code in **TF 2.x** as shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

a=tf.Variable(0, name='input')
b=tf.constant(1)

mid_val =tf.add(a,b)
update_value =tf.compat.v1.assign(a,mid_val)
tg=tf.compat.v1.initialize_all_variables()   #add tf.compat.v1 to initialize_all_variables() function


with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tg)
  print(sess.run(a))

  for i in range(3):
    sess.run(update_value)
    print(sess.run(a))
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Or can use `%tensorflow_version 1.x` to convert TensorFlow as in graph mode before running the above code.